# When two optionals are assigned to an if let statement, which one gets unwrapped? Swift language

Tags: swift, option-type

So if I have some code as written below

```
func currentWeatherDictionaryfromjsonDictionary (jsonDictionary: [String: AnyObject]? ) -> CurrentWeather? {
    if let currentWeatherama = jsonDictionary?["currently"] as? [String: AnyObject] {...
```

Now there are two options in the `if let` statement, the first is `jsonDictionary`? and the second is the optional returned from accessing the dictionary which is casted to an optional(since the key might not exist).

The question is which optional does this `if let` statement unwrap, or is it both?

I thought the code will only unwrap the second optional but when i played around in the playground it seemed like jsonDictionary was unwrapped as well. Was wondering if I was right since I am quite new to this. And also where can I find out more about syntax besides the official swift guide, because that guide does not go into specifics in a number of cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is an "Optional chain" - a series of commands, which is aborted in the middle if any one of them fails. There are actually four (or maybe five) things happening here:

```
if let currentWeatherama = jsonDictionary?["currently"] as? [String: AnyObject]
```

- The first `?` tests whether `jsonDictionary`, an Optional, can be safely unwrapped;
- if that worked, the resulting Dictionary's `["currently"]` key's value is fetched, yielding a new Optional;
- a single command, `as?` does *two* things:

  - it tests whether that Optional can be safely unwrapped, and
  - it tests whether the resulting unwrapped value can be safely cast down to a Dictionary;
- if that worked, the result is assigned to `currentWeatherama`

If there is any failure along the way, the `if` test simply fails silently and safely.

Comment: You also asked for further reading. Here's my book, on Optionals: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_optional - on casting: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_casting - on Dictionaries: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_dictionary - and, finally, on the `if let` syntax: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_conditional_binding

Comment: @anishparajuli Thanks, I'm happy if I'm able to help!